# How to get the a href link from under the div class?

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the `href` attribute from links from a page, but I end up with `[]` as the ouput

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw">
  <div class="style__product-card___1gbex style__card___3eL67 style__raised___3MFEA style__white-bg___10nDR style__overflow-hidden___2maTX">
   <a href="/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629" target="_blank" class="button-text style__flex-row___2AKyf style__flex-1___A_qoj style__product-name___HASYw">
  </div>
  </div>
```

The code used for scraping:

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw'})]
print(links)
```

My desired output is:

```
/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this want you want?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<div class="style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw">
  <div class="style__product-card___1gbex style__card___3eL67 style__raised___3MFEA style__white-bg___10nDR style__overflow-hidden___2maTX">
   <a href="/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629" target="_blank" class="button-text style__flex-row___2AKyf style__flex-1___A_qoj style__product-name___HASYw">
  </div>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw'})
links = [i.find("a")["href"] for i in soup]

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629
```

Comment: It will work... Unless You have multiple `a` tags inside inner `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `href` from the inner `div`, not `a` tag. To get all links from the wanted `div`, You could use something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

div_tag = """
    <div class="style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw">
        <div class="style__product-card___1gbex style__card___3eL67 style__raised___3MFEA style__white-bg___10nDR style__overflow-hidden___2maTX">
            <a href="/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629" target="_blank" class="button-text style__flex-row___2AKyf style__flex-1___A_qoj style__product-name___HASYw">
        </div>
    </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(div_tag, features="html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all("div", "style__width-100p___2woP5 style__flex-row___m8FHw"):
    for a in div.find_all("a"):
        print(a["href"])
```